# PHP function return value of exception or none

Tags: php, return-type

PHP 8 brought many nice features, one being union types for return values of functions.

One issue I am sitting with, where I can not use the union types declaration, is when I either want to return a void, or a value. This behaviour is however not allowed in PHP, and I am simply wondering if anyone has some way to counter this in a good way.

In my case I am using Meilisearch, and am wanting to perform a simple check inside a try catch block to see if an index exists. If it does, simply return nothing. If it doesn't, return an exception to the user.

```
public function deleteIndex(string $index)
{
    try {
        $meiliIndex = $this->client->index($index)->fetchInfo();
    } catch (ApiException $e) {
        Log::channel('meilisearch')->error($e);
        return $e; 
    }

    $meiliIndex->delete();
}
```

Anyone have any tips on a way to make this work?

Comment: To return an exception is strange. Why not throw it again?

Comment: Yes throwing works fine, but since I am calling this method from a command, I would like to return the exception back to the command to allow me to handle it.

Comment: Just return null so u can have union type null|string that'll work.
So you can return null or the error but yeah void isn't allowed in union types cause either you return something or you don't.

Comment: You could return an object containing state and message.

Comment: You should indeed use a nullable, then. Besides type hinting, there is no practical difference between `return null` and `return`.

Comment: Most likely it will end up overcomplicating things, and I am better off just throwing the exception as it is